# Style <a> link one time different style

Tags: html, css

html:

```
<div id="content">
<p> some text </p>
<a href="#"> some link aaa </a>
<a href="#"> some other link bbb</a>
</div>
```

css :

```
#content a 
{
color: #red;
text-decoration: underline;
}

.blue { color: #blue; }
```

I like to style "some other link bbb" with the css. But I like the other link to be a different color. I try adding class to the  and  but no luck.. it overwrite by the a

how should i do that ?

so why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="content">
<p> some text </p>
<a href="#" class="f"> some link aaa </a>
<a href="#" class="f2"> some other link bbb</a>
</div>

#content a.f
    {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
    }

    #content a.f2 
    {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

it's a specificity issue. try changing `.blue` to `#content a.blue`

Answer (score 2):

You have a CSS specificity problem there. HTML Dog has [a good tutorial](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/) on this.

From the article:

> The actual specificity of a group of nested selectors takes some
>   calculating. Basically, you give every id selector ("#whatever") a
>   value of 100, every class selector (".whatever") a value of 10 and
>   every HTML selector ("whatever") a value of 1. Then you add them all
>   up and hey presto, you have the specificity value.

Comment: WOW, HTML Dog make it clear as water !.. every web designer/programmer should understand that before writting CSS !, thanks x1000

Answer (score 1):

change

```
.blue { color: blue; }
```

to

```
#content a.blue { color: blue; }
```

EDIT: the id is preventing it.  The id takes precedence.
also, the # is not valid.

Comment: why you tell me that : the # is not valid. ?

Comment: On a second look, he's referring to the #'s before your CSS colors. Hash tags are only used before color hex values, not color names.

Comment: @menardmam oops! sorry.  Yes, I meant the color names.  You can use hexadecimal values for colors or color names (what you are using now) or syntax like rgb() or hsla().  When you use color names, you need to just use the names and not #color.